# Is it possible, using the "speech_to_text" library, to set a time before ending the audio input after the end of the user's sentence?

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm writing a code to recognize the user's speech and from it make decisions within the application, but we know that when we're talking we can have brief interruptions to think better about the words, that's when my problem starts, when I cut my sentence and wait for a second and I start to speak the program cancels the audio input and does not listen to the second part, I would like to know if there is any method from the "speech_to_text" library that I can define for it to wait at least 3 seconds after the end of the user's speech to ensure there are no mistakes in capturing your phrase.

This is my backend code to work with speech:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

class Speech {
    static final _speech = SpeechToText();
    static Timer? _timer;
    static Future<bool> toggleRecording({required Function(String text) onResult, required ValueChanged<bool> onListening}) async {
      final isAvailable = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (status) {
          return onListening(_speech.isListening);
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print('Error $error');
        },

      );
      if (isAvailable) {
        _speech.listen(
          partialResults: true,
          onResult: (value) {
            onResult(value.recognizedWords);
            print(onResult(value.recognizedWords));

          },
          listenFor: Duration(seconds: 10),
        );
      }
      return isAvailable;
    }
  }
```

this is my frontend code for UI:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const HomePage({super.key});

    @override
    State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    String textSample = 'Click button to start recording', _recognizedText = "";
    bool isListening = false;
    final  _speech = SpeechToText();
 
    void startListening() {
      _speech.listen(onResult: (val) {
        setState(() {
          // Atribua o texto reconhecido a uma variável
          _recognizedText = val.recognizedWords;
        });
        print(_recognizedText);
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "Reconhecimento de Voz",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          // Copiando o texto para "clipboard"
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // Colocando o texto na "clipboard"
                await FlutterClipboard.copy(textSample);
                // Fazendo aparecer um "toast"
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Text Copied to Clipboard')),
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.copy,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
          endRadius: 80,
          animate: isListening,
          glowColor: Colors.teal,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: toggleRecording,
            child: Icon(
              isListening ? Icons.circle : Icons.mic,
              size: 35,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0).copyWith(bottom: 140),
            child: SubstringHighlight(
              text: textSample,
              terms: Command.commands,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.teal,
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
              textStyleHighlight: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Future toggleRecording() {
      return Speech.toggleRecording(
        onResult: (String text) {
          setState(() {
            textSample = text;
          });
        },
        onListening: (bool isListening) {
          setState(() {
            this.isListening = isListening;
          });
          if (!isListening) {
            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
              Utils.scanVoicedText(textSample);
            });
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

***Please ignore "Utils", "SubstringHighlight" methods***